# SwiftUI - Asset Validation Failed During Distribute

Tags: swift, swiftui, app-store-connect, archive, testflight

I wanna test my SwiftUI app on TestFlight and then I'll release the app on App Store. However, I get an error during Distribute App processing. I do Archive and Distribute App with TestFlight & App Store option and then I get "Assert Validation Failed" see below.

[Assert Validation Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExWGm.png)

When I check output of compiling, I see a few warnings. You can see below.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFYxO.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SeTL.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPdev.png)

I totally do not understand what problem is. How can I solve this problem ?

Xcode Version: 15.0.1 (15A507)
SwiftUI Version : 16.0

I try to test my swiftUI application on TestFlight. But I cannot update to App Store Connect.